# Dangerous affection

Tags: word, knowledge, letters

This word means "(ability) to impose affection", good or malicious.

But if broken apart, the spelling of the parts would mean "to witness damage".

What is this word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word is:

> Charm

Which could be read as:

> See harm

Comment: Right! Was it too easy, perhaps?